# Android Google Map : Error in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin

I used google map in android version new 2.2 and I get same messages error in messages gradle build.
[image]

and event log
[image]

I don't know where is the problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your project is exceeding 65536 methods. This is likely because you are importing the whole Google Play Services library doing

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

You can import only the modules that you are going to use. If you are only using Google Maps you can change your Play Services dependency to be

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
}
```